# How to use object attribute in the class attribute

Tags: python, class, object, oop

How to use object attribute in the class attribute?

```
class UserSerializer(Model):

    def sectorret(self):
        sector= self.context["sectname"]
        return sector

    user = Users.objects.using(
        f'db-{sector}').all()
```

This return error, (ofcourse), because sector is not defined in reachable space. How do I reach it ? tried using `self` didnt work because its in class and self is not defined.

```
 user = Users.objects.using(
            f'db-{self.sector}').all()
```

tried this too, didnt work, missing 1 positional argument:

```
 user = Users.objects.using(
            f'db-{sectorret()}').all()
```

Comment: You... don't. There is no `self` when defining class attributes. You need to make an instance for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `__init__` constructor method for initialize class attributes as below.

```py
class UserSerializer(Model):

    def __init__(self):
        self.sector = self.context["sectname"]
        self.user = Users.objects.using(f'db-{self.sector}').all()
```

Then you can create object instance for accessing as below

```py
user_serializer = UserSerializer()
print(user_serializer.sector)
print(user_serializer.user)
```

Comment: unfortunately, that's not what I want. I want the `user` stays as class attribute. what you are doing is changing it to instance attribute. Thanks for responding to my question though.